# Vague error in Vercel deployment (exit with code 1)

Tags: next.js, vercel

So normally Vercel gives me decent error messages, but this one seems to have no detail. Just

> "failed with exit code 1".

For context, I just started this project w the basic NextJS template, made a few modifications, and this is my first deploy.

Failed once and I assumed it was because NextJS has strict type checking on by default, so I modified the `next.config.js` file as follows (per [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/ignoring-typescript-errors)):

```
module.exports = {
  typescript: {
    // !! WARN !!
    // Dangerously allow production builds to successfully complete even if
    // your project has type errors.
    // !! WARN !!
    ignoreBuildErrors: true,
  },
};
```

But still failed. Here is the full log:

```
10:23:27.575    Cloning github.com/lawderp/physical (Branch: main, Commit: 8f97554)
10:23:28.589    Cloning completed: 1.014s
10:23:28.614    Analyzing source code...
10:23:29.739    Installing build runtime...
10:23:31.612    Build runtime installed: 1.873s
10:23:34.043    Looking up build cache...
10:23:34.164    Build cache found. Downloading...
10:23:35.100    Build cache downloaded [21.48 MB]: 936.007ms
10:23:36.250    Installing dependencies...
10:23:36.489    yarn install v1.22.11
10:23:36.547    [1/4] Resolving packages...
10:23:36.734    success Already up-to-date.
10:23:36.743    Done in 0.26s.
10:23:36.754    Detected Next.js version: 11.1.2
10:23:36.755    Running "yarn run build"
10:23:37.021    yarn run v1.22.11
10:23:37.047    $ next build
10:23:37.820    info  - Using webpack 5. Reason: Enabled by default https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/webpack5
10:23:37.976    info  - Skipping validation of types...
10:23:40.439    error Command failed with exit code 1.
10:23:40.439    info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
10:23:40.456    Error: Command "yarn run build" exited with 1
```

Comment: Could you provide a [mre]?

Answer (score 0):

Still not sure what the issue was but eventually figured out how to get past this - ignored ESLint during build by adding the following to `next.config.js`:

```
eslint: {
    ignoreDuringBuilds: true,
  },
```

(I don't advise doing this but this was quick low-stakes experiment)

Answer (score 0):

I received the same vague message after making eslint alterations. Locally linting and deployment was successful, however deploying to vercel failed like yours.

Although `"ignoreDuringBuilds": "true"` in my `.eslint.json` did band-aid fix the issue, I was able to rollback each eslint change and found that my `"linebreak-style": ["error", "windows"]` was the underlying issue.

It passed linting locally, but failed on vercel deployment. I've fixed my line-breaks and all works great now without having to ignore during builds.